# Trouble while executing shell command inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a below mentioned Json file. And i need to parse this file with an input argument that i will pass to my shell script. So Basically i need to parse the values which are inside "collection" from the below JSON file. So if i will pass Janan as a input argument then i need Janan_2 as output or if i pass Janan_ex1 then i need Janan_loc_data as output

Input: abc.txt

```
{"znode":{
    "path":"/aliases.json","prop":{
      "ver":23,
      "aver":10,
      "count":0,
      "time":"Sat Mar 07 04:39:53 GMT 2015 (1425703193598)",
      "cver":0,
      "czxid":123,
      "Owner":0,
      "mtime":"Tue Sep 22 05:59:16 GMT 2015 (1442901556990)",
      "mzxid":123,
      "pzxid":463856470714,
      "dataLength":272},
    "data":"{\"collection\":{\n    \"Janan\":\"Janan_2\",\n    \"Janan_ex1\":\"Janan_loc_data\",\n    \"Neha\":\"Neha_1\",\n    \"cric\":\"cric_2\",\n    \"San\":\"San_1\",\n    \"Arp\":\"Arp_1\",\n    \"Nipun_test4\":\"Nipun_test3\",\n    \"tran_Nipun\":\"tran_Nipun_2\",\n    \"Zing\":\"Zing_1\"}}"},"tree":[{"data":{
        "title":"/aliases.json","attr":{
          "href":"zookeeper?detail=true&path=%2Faliases.json"}}}]}
```

So actually issue is that i am not able to fetch the values when i am using my command inside my shell and the same command is working fine while running in command line.

Below command is working fine while running at command line

```
cat abc.txt | awk -v RS=',?\\\\n[[:space:]]+' 'gsub(/\\"/,"")' | cut -d"{" -f3,3 |  cut -d"}" -f1,1 | grep Janan_ex1 | cut -d":" -f2,2
```

output from above is : `Janan_loc_data`

But when i am using it inside my shell script, with the below arguments

```
INPUT=Janan_ex1
alias_1="user/arpan/abc.txt"

alias_2=`cat $alias_1 | awk -v RS=',?\\\\n[[:space:]]+' 'gsub(/\\"/,"")' | cut -d"{" -f3,3 |  cut -d"}" -f1,1 | grep $INPUT | cut -d":" -f2,2`
```

OUTPUT:-

```
\atm_2\,\n    \atm_ex1\
```

This is because it is not able to read special character \ inside shell scripts

For below command when using inside the script,

```
alias_2=`cat $alias_1 | awk -v RS=',?\\\\n[[:space:]]+' 'gsub(/\\"/,"")' | cut -d"{" -f3,3 |  cut -d"}" -f1,1 | grep $INPUT`
```

I am getting below output:-

```
 \n    \Janan\:\Janan_2\,\n    \Janan_ex1\:\Janan_loc_data\,\n    \dps\:\dps_1\,\n    \ammf\:\ammf_2\,\n    \mob_search\:\mob_search_1\,\n    \dnb\:\dnb_1\,\n    \stamping_test4\:\stamping_test3\,\n    \tran_stamping\:\tran_stamping_2\,\n    \mrch_generic\:\mrch_generic_1\
```

### Also i cannot use json parser inside my script as it is not installed in machine

### Details regarding my unix flavor

```
$ uname -a
Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 10 09:44:54 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Then install a JSON parser (like `jq`). `awk` was designed for line-oriented text, not structured input like JSON.

Comment: Chepner It is not possible to install at our production env..needs lots of approval and take lots of days to do it and i need it by EOD today.

Comment: Without a structured tool try an unstructured approach. Something like `grep collection abc.txt | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\\"/\n/g' -e 's/}}"},.*//' -e 's/\\",\\n//g'  -e 's/\\"//g' ` and see if you can use the output for the translation.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you install a JSON parser; it's the right tool for the job. Here's how you would solve your problem with `jq`:

```
$ jq '.znode.data | fromjson | .collection.Janon' abc.txt
"Janan_2"
$ jq '.znode.data | fromjson | .collection.Janon_ex1' abc.txt
"Janan_loc_data"
```

In general, you could use the `--arg` option:

```
$ jq --arg field Janan '.znode.data | fromjson | .collection | .[$field]' abc.txt
"Janan_2"
```

---

For now, try using `$(...)` instead of backticks; they treat backslashes *slightly* differently. Using your code, I get an output of `\Janan_loc_data\`, but with the following, I get `Janan_loc_data`.

```
alias_2=$(awk -v RS=',?\\\\n[[:space:]]+' 'gsub(/\\"/,"")' "$alias_1" |
           cut -d"{" -f3,3 |  cut -d"}" -f1,1 | grep "$INPUT" | cut -d":" -f2,2)
```

Comment: Hi Chepner, i have already mentioned this to our unix admin ..but not getting a  proper response ..as of now i cannot use it :(

Comment: @Arpan If you compile it from source you can probably install it in your home directory without `sudo`

Comment: @user000001 : But it will only hold good for my dev environment ..it wont work for production as jq is not installed at production as well. .. Plus there are lots of restriction here while doing any new installation ..